# How do I add border to an @IBAction Button that is linked from storyboard in Swift 2.1?

Tags: uibutton, swift2, xcode7, ibaction, xcode-storyboard

How to set button border if the button is linked to storyboard and is of type @IBAction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button's type is not IBAction, the IBAction is the connection between the storyboard and the function

if you want to change the button in the code, connect it from the storyboard as an outlet
(hold ctrl and drag the button from storyboard to your viewController)

(and u can also change it from the storyboard)